# Laravel HasManyThrough, accesing Primary/Secondary user referrals

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have an app where I need to track a user's primary and secondary referrals. My user table looks like:

users table

- name, varchar
- email, varchar
- **referral_id**, varchar
- **referrer_id**, varchar

I currently access the primary referrals/referrer using the following:

```
public function referrer() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'referrer_id', 'referral_id');
}

public function primaryReferrals() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'referrer_id', 'referral_id');
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can access the "secondary" referrals...for example.

User A invites User B. User B then invites Users D, E, F. From the User A model I want to be able to call something like `$user->secondaryReferrals` and get users D, E, F.

I'm guessing I need to use something like:

```
public function secondaryReferrals() 
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        User::class, 
        User::class, 
        'referrer_id', 
        'referrer_id', 
        'referral_id', 
        'referral_id'
    );
}
```

However I'm not clear on what keys/ids I should be supplying...or if this is even the right bit to use. I tried a mix but I keep getting `ambiguous column name` errors when using sqlite and other errors when using the mysql driver.

UserA: {
  referer_id: null,
  referral_id: 'abc'
}

UserB: {
  referrer_id: 'abc',
  referral_id: 'def'
}

UserC: {
  referrer_id: 'def',
  referral_id: 'ghi'
}

I want to be able to access User C from User A through User B's referral code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a `HasManyThrough` relationship here because there is no way to specify a table alias.

You can use the `primaryReferrals` relationship twice:

```php
public function getSecondaryReferralsAttribute() 
{
    $this->load('primaryReferrals.primaryReferrals');

    return $this->primaryReferrals->pluck('primaryReferrals')->flatten();
}

// $user->secondaryReferrals
```

Comment: If you would like to have a direct relationship, you can use a package I created: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep